# 400MB free ram but cant delete WhatsApp chats

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, crashes, ram, system-freeze

I have a **samsung galaxy J3 2016** (SM-J320FN)
I bought it **brandnew** like 6/7 months ago,

Ive got a tiny **8gb** internal storage plus a **32gb sd-card**,
Got all my applications and files and stuff moved to my sdcard.

But i still run out of internal storage almost twice a week.
I don't have mutch applications on it either,

I **cant** even delete some whatsapp groupchats,
It just **keeps loading**.

And then it wil **freeze** and not mutch later **crash**..
Sometimes he won't even send pictures over WhatsApp.
Or cant update my profile picture cuz then it **will just freeze and crash again**

I've tried to reinstall WhatsApp multiple times and it doesn't help,
And the weird thing is i have **400+mb free ram**  atm

So i don't really know what to do anymore anyone suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

*I am not responsible for lost data*
Try to do this:

1. Uninstall whatsapp
2. Search in internal storage the whatsapp folder
3. Delete it
4. Reboot your phone
5. Reinstall whatsapp and DON'T restore backups

If this procedure doesn't work, I think it is a good idea resetting your phone.
Unfortunately devices like your have this type of problems frow the dawn of the times and the only solution often is the total wipe

Comment: I understand                                              Thanks man haha gonna try it out